# Is it possible to only display particular category posts on the Tumblr frontpage

Tags: tumblr

Is it possible to only display particular category (e.g. 'homepage') posts on the Tumblr frontpage?

The other categories I want to be available using a 'redirect' page which.

Answer (score 0):

No not possible unfortunately.

Only possible is there to hide certain categories using css.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394655/in-tumblr-show-only-posts-with-a-certain-tag-in-the-home-page/29481650#29481650).

The short answer is yes, but Marcel Overdijk is correct in that the only solution is hiding posts via CSS. Basically we're just hiding the posts that don't have a "featured" tag with "display:none;".

Follow this guide:

(Inspired by mircealungu's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162291/3518948).)

**1.** Find the article tag, and add the classname:

class="**notfeatured {TagsAsClasses}**"

If it already has a classname, add the part in bold above inside the classname quotes. Mine ended up looking like this:

```
<article id="{PostID}" class="post notfeatured {TagsAsClasses} {PostType}{block:PermalinkPage} {block:Date}not-{/block:Date}page{/block:PermalinkPage}">
```

**2.** Find the div tag that precedes the article tag, and add the classname:

class="**{block:TagPage} tag_page {/block:TagPage}{block:PermalinkPage}perma_page{/block:PermalinkPage}**"

Again, if a class already exists, just add the part in bold above inside the classname quotes. Mine ended up like this:

```
<div id="posts" class="{block:TagPage} tag_page {/block:TagPage}{block:PermalinkPage}perma_page{/block:PermalinkPage}" >
```

**3.** Finally, add this to your CSS:

```
article.notfeatured {display: none;}
article.featured, .tag_page article.notfeatured, .perma_page article.notfeatured {display: block;}
```

Now any post tagged as "featured" will display on your home page, but nothing else. So far no issues for me, it works great! You can see it [here](http://47togo.com).