# How can I display only posts with a specific tag in one column on a tumblr theme, and leave the other column for "general population" posts?

Tags: html, css, tags, themes, tumblr

I am looking to edit my theme so that one column (or section or area or really anything on the home page of my blog) displays posts only tagged a certain thing (for example, "mine," or "personal") and the other column (or section or area or thing on the home page) displays "general population posts" or, all posts with or without that special tag.

I have looked at a few questions on this site with similar queries, including
[Trying to add tagged posts section to sidebar (not text but images) - Tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469203/trying-to-add-tagged-posts-section-to-sidebar-not-text-but-images-tumblr) and 
[In tumblr, show only posts with a certain tag in the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394655/in-tumblr-show-only-posts-with-a-certain-tag-in-the-home-page)
but neither really answered what I want to do, nor did they give me any answer that I'm looking for.

This question: [tumblr post specification container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756575/tumblr-post-specification-container) had very close to what I want to do, but I cannot understand what the asker did to achieve this, or how to modify it to fit what I want.

I have some experience with HTML, but I have not really used it in a very long time, so I was wondering if any of you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone wanting to do this, try the {TagsAsClasses} variable in Tumblr, and use some Javascript to manipulate the display of the posts. [Here's the link to Tumblr's theming how to](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes), and also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29481650/3518948) for inspiration. I have it working on [my blog](http://47togo.com) right now.